# Can I tell MySQL what to cache?

Tags: mysql, cache, query-cache

Pretty straightforward question:

Let's say I have a specific query that I know is regularly used, can I tell MySQL to always cache it "automatically" ... i.e. once the cached query results are flushed the `mysqld` immediately runs that query again to have the cached data ready for the next user?

Or the other way round: can I tell MySQL to not cache specific queries?
What about other caching options, not necessarily related to queries?

I searched through the web on this but can't really find anything related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL Documentation has [**SQL_NO_CACHE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) option:

> Two query cache-related options may be specified in SELECT statements:
>
> SQL_CACHE
>
> The query result is cached if it is cacheable and the value of the
>   query_cache_type system variable is ON or DEMAND.
>
> SQL_NO_CACHE
>
> The server does not use the query cache. It neither checks the query
>   cache to see whether the result is already cached, nor does it cache
>   the query result. (Due to a limitation in the parser, a space
>   character must precede and follow the SQL_NO_CACHE keyword; a nonspace
>   such as a newline causes the server to check the query cache to see
>   whether the result is already cached.)
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT SQL_CACHE id, name FROM customer;
> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer;
> ```

You can set SQL_NO_CACHE as the default for your session by setting [**query_cache_type**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type)

```
SET query_cache_type = 'DEMAND';
```

or

```
SET query_cache_type = 2;
```

Afterwards, you must say `SELECT SQL_CACHE` to make it cache the `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. MySQL don't have that mechanism. The common featues which are misunderstood about query cache

1. Only works for SELECT queries
2. Queries should be absolutely identical
3. **It is  not possible to see query cache contents**

We can only optimize the parameters

```
query_cache_limit = 150K
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
```

Rather, we should disable query cache where there is frequent UPDATE and INSERT as once there is any change in table, nullifies all SELECTs under query cache. It is seen that disabling query cache improved performance in these scenarios

Comment: `query_cache_size = 512M` is dangerously high.  This is because of inefficiencies in purging the query cache whenever a write occurs.  I recommend no bigger than 50M.